# How do I apply read and write consistency in gocql?

Tags: go, cassandra, cql, gocql

I am using https://github.com/gocql/gocql.
I want to set the read/write consistency of cassandra.

```
cluster := gocql.NewCluster(hosts...)
cluster.Consistency = gocql.ParseConsistency(consistency)
```

If the consistency setting is applied as above, is both read/write consistency applied?
Or is there a way to apply read and write consistency separately?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the global consistency with:

```
    cluster.Consistency = gocql.LocalQuorum
```

This will apply to both reads and writes. There is no way to configure a different CL for either just reads or just writes with the GoCQL driver.

As an alternative, you can set the consistency for the session or just the query with either `Consistency()` or `SetConsistency()`. For example:

```
    session.Query(query, ...).Consistency(gocql.One)
```

The valid [consistency constants](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gocql/gocql#Consistency) are:

```
    Any
    One
    Two
    Three
    Quorum
    All
    LocalQuorum
    EachQuorum
    LocalOne
```

Note that the general recommendation is to use local quorum for almost all cases. Cheers!

Comment: If there is only one datacenter, are Quorum and LocalQuorum the same?

Comment: Yes, but we recommend using `LocalQuorum` in your app to future-proof it -- you don't need to recompile your code when you add a new DC in the future. Cheers!